# How to configure appearance/theme of KDE Dolphin app

Tags: arch-linux, kde, theme, dolphin

I am using a Raspberry Pi astronomy package that runs under Arch-Linux and KDE. Amateur astronomers often prefer keeping their computer screens very dark to avoid light pollution.  But my use of this package will be done from indoors with a wifi connection to the Raspberry Pi which sits on the telescope. So keeping it dark is not a concern for me. In fact I often play with the system during the day when bright light makes a dark theme even harder to read,

The designers of this package picked some really weird color themes for certain applications, such as the Dolphin File Manager that comes with the package, to preserve dark screens. I was able to change the theme, but this only applied to the left-pane of Dolphin (which was previously dark), not the right pane, making for a look like this:

[image: Dolphin screen]

There actually is text next to the folders but it's impossible to read.

What config files would I have to change to make a more reasonable color scheme?

Answer (score 0):

In the file `~/.config/kdeglobals`, under the `[Colors:View]` section, the `BackgroundNormal=` colour is what Dolphin uses.

So if you want to set it to white:

`BackgroundNormal=255,255,255` or `BackgroundNormal=#FFFFFF` (it takes either RGB or HEX)

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dolphin#Mismatched_folder_view_background_colors